# Expand column containing list of tuples into the current dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_with_tuples': [[('word1', 10), ('word2', 20), ('word3', 30)], [('word4', 40), ('word5', 50), ('word6', 60)]],
                   'category':['category1','category2']})
```

I want to move the tuples into two separate columns and preserve the category column to be able to easily filter the most common words for each category.

So the final result should look like this:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'word': ['word1','word2', 'word3','word4','word5','word6'],
                   'frequency': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
                   'category':['category1','category1', 'category1', 'category2', 'category2', 'category2']})
```

I tried with this code but the result is not the one I expect:

```
df_tuples = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x) for x in df['column_with_tuples']], ignore_index=True)

df_tuples.columns = ['word', 'frequency']

df.drop(['column_with_tuples'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df = pd.concat([df, df_tuples], axis=1)
```

I would appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) method to expand the tuples in the `column_with_tuples` column into separate rows. After that, introduce `.rename()` method to change the name of the column, then unpack the tuples into separate columns and add the `category` column using the `.apply()` method. And finally `assign()` method to add the `category` column to the your dataframe.

```py
df_new = df.explode("column_with_tuples")
df_new = df_new.rename(columns={"column_with_tuples": "word"})
df_new[["word", "frequency"]] = df_new["word"].apply(pd.Series)

df_new = df_new.assign(category=df["category"])
df_new = df_new[["word", "frequency", "category"]]
df_new.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(df_new)
```

**Simplified version of the above code:**

```py
df_new = df.explode("column_with_tuples").rename(columns={"column_with_tuples": "word"})
df_new[["word", "frequency"]] = df_new["word"].apply(pd.Series)
df_new.assign(category=df["category"])

df_new = df_new[["word", "frequency", "category"]].reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_new)
```

---

```
    word  frequency   category
0  word1         10  category1
1  word2         20  category1
2  word3         30  category1
3  word4         40  category2
4  word5         50  category2
5  word6         60  category2
```

Comment: I had forgotten about the `explode()` func. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can initially explode `column_with_tuples` into multiple rows and then build a multiindex from a series of tuples `(word, freaquency)` with [`pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html):

```
df2 = df.explode('column_with_tuples')
df2.set_index(pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df2['column_with_tuples']))\
    .reset_index(names=['word', 'frequency']).drop(columns='column_with_tuples')
```

---

```
   word  frequency   category
0  word1         10  category1
1  word2         20  category1
2  word3         30  category1
3  word4         40  category2
4  word5         50  category2
5  word6         60  category2
```

Answer (score 0):

One option with the `explode` method:

```py
(df
.explode('column_with_tuples')
.assign(word = lambda df: df.column_with_tuples.str[0], 
        frequency = lambda df: df.column_with_tuples.str[1])
.drop(columns='column_with_tuples')
) 
    category   word  frequency
0  category1  word1         10
0  category1  word2         20
0  category1  word3         30
1  category2  word4         40
1  category2  word5         50
1  category2  word6         60
```

Another option, using vanilla python, before creating the final dataframe:

```py
from itertools import product, chain

out = [product([cat], tuples) 
       for cat, tuples 
       in zip(df.category, df.column_with_tuples)]

out = chain.from_iterable(out)

out = [(cat, *tuples) for cat, tuples in out]

pd.DataFrame(out, columns = ['category', 'word', 'frequency'])
    category   word  frequency
0  category1  word1         10
1  category1  word2         20
2  category1  word3         30
3  category2  word4         40
4  category2  word5         50
5  category2  word6         60
```